# VehicleBody Node on airplanes? Godot

Tags: 3d, nodes, game-engine, godot

I am trying to make a 3D game in Godot with cars, airplanes etc. The thing is: I wanted to use a RigidBody node, but VehicleBody poped up. Should I use RigidBody or VehicleBody on an airplane?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node `VehicleBody` is not intended for airplanes. I suggest against using it for that, the reason is that it contains logic regarding whether or not the wheels are in contact with the ground.

To be clear, that does not mean you need `VehicleBody` to make cars, just that it will save you some work.

---

I'm going to recommend Godot Recipes [Simplified Airplane Controller](http://kidscancode.org/godot_recipes/3d/simple_airplane/). Which, by the way, is based on `KinematicBody` instead of `RigidBody`.